# Linux users traffic measurement

Tags: linux, monitoring, users, traffic

I want to measure traffic(upload) made by each user on a linux system. 
Each users runs a rTorrent instance on a specified port. Also users could make traffic through the ftp server (vsftpd).

Is there a tool that can monitor traffic for a specified port and for ftp users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like that with [Ntop](http://www.ntop.org/). It is a little cumbersome, and last time i used it, it reset all stats on restart, but you should be able to feed ntop data into [Cacti](http://cacti.net/) for permanent  safe-keeping.

This will require some hackery, but the result will be amazing. You could also feed the data straight into rrdtool. There are some really cool graph examples on [rrdtool](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/index.en.html) site.

**UPDATE:** Here is a graph that shows pretty much exact thing you are aiming for.

[image]

Comment: as far as attaching ports to ftp accounts... you will have to do it manually, but again, that can be achieved with some scripting perhaps?

Comment: Good to know that its possible to assign ports. Scripting is not so big problem.

Comment: nice graphs, I can't wait to try your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Upload is outgoing traffic.

I suggest you to investigate the **--uid-owner** setting of *iptables* **match** module.

Answer (score 0):

I use nTop or iftop but they don't discriminate between user

Comment: I guess nTop or ifTop can measure port traffic; my question is, can I assign ports to ftp accounts ?

Comment: i use http://n0rp.chemlab.org/vlogger/ for HTTP, I don't know something like this for FTP