# Linux calculate traffic per user

Tags: ubuntu, traffic

I have ubuntu server with several processes (some java, some scripting) accessing the internet. Every process runs under it own user.

I would like to find out stats about network usage for these users. How can I configure this in ubuntu?

thank you

Comment: It's hard to tell where this one should go (Webmasters?  Ubuntu?) but it's off-topic here, not having anything to do with programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux users traffic measurement](http://serverfault.com/questions/133949/linux-users-traffic-measurement), and see also [Network bandwidth monitoring per user on ubuntu server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28926/network-bandwidth-monitoring-per-user-on-ubuntu-server)